# PHP For Each Running Through 2 Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, image

Thanks for trying to solve my problem!

Here is my code...

```
$j = 0;

foreach(array_count_values($Drink_Id) as $key=>$value) {
    if ($j != 0) {
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            echo "<li><img src='Images/BeerGlassIcon.gif' alt='Beer Glass' class='ui-li-icon'> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a style='padding-left: 40px;' href='drink.php?did=$key&count=$value&date=today'>".$Beers[$key]."</a> <span class='ui-li-count'>$value</span></li>";
        } else {
            echo "<li><img src='Images/BeerGlassIcon.gif' alt='Beer Glass' class='ui-li-icon'> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a style='padding-left: 40px;' href='drink.php?did=$key&count=$value&date=today'>".$key."</a> <span class='ui-li-count'>$value</span></li>";
        }
    }
    $j++;
}
```

Basically the code skips the first result in the array and echos a li with some information from the array.

The problem is I have another array: $Type_Id

The arrays $Drink_Id and $Type_Id are very related and $Drink_Id[32] is related to $Type[32].

How can I interweave the arrays to be running at the same time in the foreach() loop?

So my foreach() statement would look a little like this (I guess).

```
foreach(array_count_values($Drink_Id) as $key=>$value && array_count_values($Type_Id) as $key_2=>$value_2 )
```

How can I do a statement like the one above, but one that actually works?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your $Drink_Id and $Type_Id arrays?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a regular for loop and the same counter variable for both arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you use ‘for’ loop instead of ‘foreach’